# How to filter nested array and compute the time difference

Tags: javascript

I would like to filter nested array based on two dates from `2020-04-24` up to `2020-04-25` and i would like to know the number of hours difference between 'in' and 'out' of each day of each name.

```
const databases =  [{
  name: 'Mark',
  time: [{
    "date": "2020-04-23T00:14:03.217Z",
    "nature": "In",
    },
    {
    "date": "2020-04-23T15:14:03.217Z",
    "nature": "Out",
    },
    {
    "date": "2020-04-24T00:14:03.217Z",
    "nature": "In",
    },
    {
    "date": "2020-04-24T15:14:03.217Z",
    "nature": "Out",
    },
    {
    "date": "2020-04-25T00:14:03.217Z",
    "nature": "In",
    },
    {
    "date": "2020-04-25T15:14:03.217Z",
    "nature": "Out",
    },
    {
    "date": "2020-04-26T080:14:03.217Z",
    "nature": "In",
    },
    {
    "date": "2020-04-26T15:14:03.217Z",
    "nature": "Out",
    }]
  },
  {
    name: 'David',
    time: [{
      "date": "2020-04-23T08:14:03.217Z",
      "nature": "In",
      },
      {
      "date": "2020-04-23T15:14:03.217Z",
      "nature": "Out",
      },
      {
      "date": "2020-04-24T10:14:03.217Z",
      "nature": "In",
      },
      {
      "date": "2020-04-24T15:14:03.217Z",
      "nature": "Out",
      },
      {
      "date": "2020-04-26T10:14:03.217Z",
      "nature": "In",
      },
      {
      "date": "2020-04-26T15:14:03.217Z",
      "nature": "Out",
      },
      {
      "date": "2020-04-27T10:10:03.217Z",
      "nature": "In",
      },
      {
      "date": "2020-04-27T15:14:03.217Z",
      "nature": "Out",
      }]
```

Comment: what is your attempt, can you show what you tried, where exactly you are stuck

Comment: gotta notice all time values are same, currently all time spans will be zero.

Comment: *I would like to do something* ... isn't very stack overflow friendly. check out the [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) for more information

Comment: this is what i have tried,       const databases= this.timeDetails.map(t => {
        const time = t.time.filter(d => (d.date >= '2020-04-24T16:00:00.000Z' && d.date <= '2020-04-225T16:00:00.000Z') );
        return { ...t, time };
      })

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This

```
    const moment = require('moment');

    const databases = [
        {
            name: 'Mark',
            time: [
                {
                    "date": "2020-04-23T00:14:03.217Z",
                    "nature": "In",
                },
                {
                    "date": "2020-04-23T15:14:03.217Z",
                    "nature": "Out",
                },
                {
                    "date": "2020-04-24T00:14:03.217Z",
                    "nature": "In",
                },
                {
                    "date": "2020-04-24T15:14:03.217Z",
                    "nature": "Out",
                },
                {
                    "date": "2020-04-25T00:14:03.217Z",
                    "nature": "In",
                },
                {
                    "date": "2020-04-25T15:14:03.217Z",
                    "nature": "Out",
                },
                {
                    "date": "2020-04-26T08:14:03.217Z",
                    "nature": "In",
                },
                {
                    "date": "2020-04-26T15:14:03.217Z",
                    "nature": "Out",
                }]
        },
        {
            name: 'David',
            time: [
                {
                    "date": "2020-04-23T08:14:03.217Z",
                    "nature": "In",
                },
                {
                    "date": "2020-04-23T15:14:03.217Z",
                    "nature": "Out",
                },
                {
                    "date": "2020-04-24T10:14:03.217Z",
                    "nature": "In",
                },
                {
                    "date": "2020-04-24T15:14:03.217Z",
                    "nature": "Out",
                },
                {
                    "date": "2020-04-26T10:14:03.217Z",
                    "nature": "In",
                },
                {
                    "date": "2020-04-26T15:14:03.217Z",
                    "nature": "Out",
                },
                {
                    "date": "2020-04-27T10:10:03.217Z",
                    "nature": "In",
                },
                {
                    "date": "2020-04-27T15:14:03.217Z",
                    "nature": "Out",
                }
            ]
        }
    ]


    const databases1 = databases.map((t) => { 
        const time = t.time.filter(d =>  {
            return moment(d.date).isBetween(moment('2020-04-24T16:00:00.000Z'), moment('2020-04-25T16:00:00.000Z'))
        });
        return { ...t, time }; 
    })

    console.log(JSON.stringify(databases1));
```

Comment: Thank you this worked. I hope it's not too much, but how do I get the number of hours difference for each day, and the total number of hours for the entire selected period?

Comment: Please refer https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/difference/